# how to refactor mongoose document update code to return updated item instead of status

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I was wondering how I might be refactor the following to return the updated document.

```
const updated = await item.update(
  { name: data.name, $inc: { seq: 1 } },
  { new: true }
);
```

It's updating but returning this instead(ie value of `updated`):

```
{ n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }
```

I also just read that using `save` is recommended, but I can't find a way to add the incrementing logic with save outside of a pre save hook.  Thanks.

Comment: your update query syntax is wrong please refer [mongoose-update()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update), and if you want to update single document try [findOneAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html), if you want to update multiple document try find() and [bulkWrite()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite) or last option is `find()` and `save()`

Comment: @turivishal thank you. I tried to refactor this to use `set` like so: `item.set({ name: data.name, $inc: { seq: 1 } });`. This seems to update `name` just fine but not `seq`.

Comment: your are dong wrong, have you check provided link in first comment mongoose-update() and are you trying to find and update single document?

Comment: @turivishal. yes, I have. from what I've read on that link, it looks like I'm missing the filter/query argument, which is why I moved onto using `set`, since that matches my expectations more with modifying the item that I already have.  And yes, I am only updating a single document.

Answer (score 0):

The `update()` method returns a [WriteResult](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#successful-results) document that contains the status of the operation.

Just try [findOneAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html), `new: true` will return updated document,

```
const updated = await item.findOneAndUpdate(
  { name: data.name }, 
  { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
  { new: true }
);
```

Comment: thanks. one of my concerns about going this route was the performance penalty I'd pay for using a pattern where I already have `item` which came as a result of `findOne` and then having to run a `findOne` in the `findOneAndUpdate` again.  Is it standard to run another `findOne`-ish operation if you already have the document you want to update and want only to update it?

Comment: ah. I just found that I can just use something like `item.increment()` after `set` as two different statements. I suppose I'd prefer to have them in one, but this gives me what I'm looking for.

Comment: good you can post your solution in answer, so would be helpful for others as well.